# How to configure and use Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I am creating an HTTP Partial method in my ASP.NET Web API controller and I read this document http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-core-json-patch-partial-api-updates on how to achieve HTTP Partial methods in a controller. I get an exception when I hit the HTTP Partial endpoint that says [image]

Here is my code for the Patch method in the controller:

```
[HttpPatch("{userId}")]
public IActionResult Patch([FromRoute(Name = "userId")]Guid userId, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<User> userProperties)
{
    var indexOfUserToPartiallyUpdate = UsersInMemory.List.FindIndex(user => user.Id == userId);

    if (indexOfUserToPartiallyUpdate == -1)
    {
        return BadRequest($"user with {userId} not found.");
    }

    var originalUser = UsersInMemory.List[indexOfUserToPartiallyUpdate];

    userProperties.ApplyTo(UsersInMemory.List[indexOfUserToPartiallyUpdate], ModelState);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {  
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(ModelState);
    }

    var model = new
    {
        beforePatch = originalUser,
        afterPatch = UsersInMemory.List[indexOfUserToPartiallyUpdate]
    };

    return Ok(model);
}
```

And here is the JSON body I'm sending through postman in the HTTP PATCH request:

[image]

I feel like I need to do something in the Startup.cs file such as configuring the JsonPatchDocument but I don't know how. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think i found your issue: "Note that we always send an array of operations even if you're only sending a single operation."

Try to change your request in:

```
[
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/email",
    "value": "THIS_SOME_OTHER_EMAIL@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

Comment: Okay Thank you Vadim. I will try it out later after work and let you know if that is a solution.

Comment: That worked Vadim. Thank you very much for your response.